# ASP.Net MVC: unit test code when working with ValidationAttribute and IClientValidatable

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5

I am bit familiar with ASP.Net MVC but weak in writing unit tests. I read an article about how to write unit test code when working with these classes and interface `ValidationAttribute` and `IClientValidatable`. Here is the link to the article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990538/Unit-Testing-Data-Validation-with-MVC

I was doing custom validation. The custom validation code as follows

```
public class DateValTest
{
    [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "End Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [MyDate(ErrorMessage = "Back date entry not allowed")]
    [DateGreaterThanAttribute(otherPropertyName = "StartDate", ErrorMessage = "End date must be greater than start date")]
    public DateTime?  EndDate { get; set; }
}

public class MyDateAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public DateTime _MinDate;

    public MyDateAttribute()
    {
        _MinDate = DateTime.Today;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        DateTime _EndDat = DateTime.Parse(value.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        DateTime _CurDate = DateTime.Today;

        int cmp = _EndDat.CompareTo(_CurDate);
        if (cmp > 0)
        {
            // date1 is greater means date1 is comes after date2
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        else if (cmp < 0)
        {
            // date2 is greater means date1 is comes after date1
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            // date1 is same as date2
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()),
            ValidationType = "restrictbackdates",
        };
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("mindate", _MinDate);
        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

So, I tried to write unit test code for the above validation. Please look at my unit test code and tell me if I am going in the right direction because I do not know if I wrote it properly or miss something. please have a look.

```
[TestClass]
public class MyDateAttribute_Test
{

    [TestMethod]
    public void IsValid_Test()
    {
        var model = new MyDateAttribute { _MinDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-10) }; //set value
        ExecuteValidation(model, "Back date entry not allowed");
    }

    private void ExecuteValidation(object model, string exceptionMessage)
    {
        try
        {
            var contex = new ValidationContext(model);
            Validator.ValidateObject(model, contex);
        }
        catch (ValidationException exc)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(exceptionMessage, exc.Message);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

**Do I need to use `Assert.AreEqual()` in try block too or should it be only in catch block?**

Comment: As far as is your test right, if you are writing the tests after the code, then once your test passed, the best approach is usually to change the code you are trying to test and make sure your test fails as expected.

Comment: not clear what u try to say :(

Comment: @Thomas, I have deleted your 2nd question (one at a time please - the answer for the 1st one will be long enough so ask a new question for the 2nd one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason at all to be using a `try/catch` block in your `TestMethod`.

Firstly your attribute is implementing `IClientValidatable` which means you want client side validation and you can only provide one message to the `ModelClientValidationRule` which in turn passes it the the `jQuery.Validator`.

The second part of article you linked to seems to be for testing cases where you might returns different error messages based on certain conditions which cannot apply when using client side validation, and in your case, you only have one error message anyway, so all you need to test is that an invalid model will return a `ValidationException`.

Personally I cannot conceive of any reason to return different error messages based on different conditions in a `ValidationAtribute`, and the correct approach would be to create separate validation attributes. Even if you were to take that approach, all its testing is that one hard code string you have written matches another hard code string inside the attribute which is a pointless test anyway. The test would only be meaningful if you were to define properties (say) `public string ErrorMessage1 { private set; get; }` and `public string ErrorMessage1 { private set; get; }` and test that the appropriate exceptions' error message matched the values of one of those properties.

Note that you can simplify your `IsValid()` method to

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    DateTime _EndDat = DateTime.Parse(value.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    int cmp = _EndDat.CompareTo(_MinDate);
    if (cmp < 0)
    {
        return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
    }
    else
    {
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Then to test that an invalid value will throw a `ValidationException`

```
// Test that a date less than today's date is invalid
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ValidationException))]
public void TestPastDateIsInvalid()
{
    DateValTest model = new DateValTest(){ EndDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1) };
    ValidationContext context = new ValidationContext(model);
    MyDateAttribute attribute = new MyDateAttribute();
    attribute.Validate(model.EndDate, context);   
}
```

Comment: what is the meaning of this line `[ExpectedException(typeof(ValidationException))]` what the ExpectedException attribute does and when to use this attribute during unit test code. please guide me.

Comment: one thing i notice u did not use `Assert.AreEqual` in unit test code....any reason ?

Comment: There is no need for `Assert.AreEqual` because all you doing is testing that a `ValidationException` will be thrown (which will happen if the model is invalid). And thats what the `[ExpectedException(typeof(ValidationException))]` does. Its basically saying _I expect to get this exception if I run this TestMethod_ (and therefore the test will pass if it does)

Comment: i post one thread again on unit test please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36100027/asp-net-mvc-how-to-write-unit-test-code-when-working-with-validationattribute-a   if possible share your code and suggestion specifically for this function like how to write unit test code for `IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules` thanks

Comment: Need a break, but will have a look in an hour or so.

Comment: thanks a lot and will be looking for help and suggestion from u in future.

Answer (score 1):

From a logical perspective, your test is fine.  That is, if `Validator.ValidateObject(model, contex);` successfully validates the object, then it neither returns anything (as it's a `void` method) nor throws an exception.  So logically there is nothing to assert here.

However, depending on your unit test framework, you may need to assert **something** to tell the framework that your test indeed did execute and was successful (some frameworks return inconclusive if you do not have a positive assertion).  So for completeness' sake I would make your method look like:

```
private void ExecuteValidation(object model, string exceptionMessage)
{
    try
    {
        var contex = new ValidationContext(model);
        Validator.ValidateObject(model, contex);
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }
    catch (ValidationException exc)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(exceptionMessage, exc.Message);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: so you just add one line `Assert.IsTrue(true);` so i guess my unit test code looks fine. thanks for your time.

Comment: i post one thread again on unit test please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36100027/asp-net-mvc-how-to-write-unit-test-code-when-working-with-validationattribute-a   if possible share your code and suggestion specifically for this function like how to write unit test code for `IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules` thanks